# What is to verbs as pronouns are to nouns?

Tags: grammar, verbs

"Mr. Hemmingway, do you write books?" "I do."

"Did Mr. Hemmingway write this book?" "He did."

Just as the pronoun "he" or "I" stands in place of the noun "Mr. Hemmingway", so the verb "do" or "did" stands in place of the very "write" or "wrote".  This is complicated by the way in which English uses "do" or "did" as an auxiliary verb in questions: maybe it could be argued that "do" or "did" in the answer is merely the same verb, "do" or "did", that is the main verb in the question.  That "do", "does", or "did" would stand in place of another verb when it is expected to be understood what the other verb is, is very far from the only way in which the verb "do" is used in English.  However, this inspires a question: **might there be, in some languages, some verbs whose only function is to bear the same relation to verbs in general that pronouns bear to nouns?**

Comment: (1) "Have you been to Paris?" "I have." (2) "Have you any money?" "I have." (3) "Do you have any money?" "I do." The form (3) is far more prevalent than (2) in present-day American English.  In both (2) and (3), just as in (1), the main verb verb in the answer is the same as the (syntactically) main verb in the question, so we're not really using a frequently used short verb to stand in place of the meaningful verb in the way "he" or "I" stands in place of "Mr. Hemmingway", but nonetheless the question was raised in my mind by such examples.

Comment: You don't need to comment your own questions, unless someone raises a discussion on an uncertain issue. Instead, please [edit](http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/posts/13035/edit) your question and place the examples within.

Comment: I think the answer to this question is simple: any word, not necessarily a verb, which expresses [**modality**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linguistic_modality), actually bears the function of noun-to-verb relation. It may or may not be used **alone**, depending on a particular language's rule of [grammatic contraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contraction_%28grammar%29).

Comment: The technical term is _Pro-verb_, usually hyphenated for obvious reasons. And there are a number of them in English, subdivided into categories depending on syntactic behavior: `Act` _do_, as in _What he did was read the angle wrong_; _do_-support _do_, as in _He didn't have any choice, did he?_; _be_ with predicate adjectives, as in _He isn't certified yet, but she has been for a year_, and so on. There's a lot of use for them.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing is to verbs as pronouns are to noun phrases.  The definite pronouns he/she/it share reference with their nominal antecedents.  Pro-verbs, however, are quite different -- they share meaning with their antecedents.

Comment: To say so one must assume that verbs refer, which is not a general assumption, as far as I understand. It's not defining of a pronoun to be anaphoric and share antecedent's reference, either.

Comment: It's the difference between first- and second-order quantified predicate calculus. Logicians don't like second-order calculus much (because it's been proven to be logically inconsistent, which means you can't rely on it algorithmically), and devised lambda calculus to nominalize predicates back to NPs, but it seems clear that that's an esthetic mathematical constraint and not a natural one. People expect every word to refer, whether it's an NP or not; or alternatively, most people's concept of _reference_ is sloppy, and their usage shows it.

Comment: @IvanKapitonov, I don't understand your comment.  I said verbs do not refer (unlike noun phrases).  That is the opposite of what you say I said.

Comment: @jlawler, second-order predicate calculus has not been shown to be inconsistent.  Quine argues that higher-order logic is equivalent to set theory, which is not known to be consistent.  Not being known to be consistent is not the same as being inconsistent.  First order logic is known to be consistent.  I do not agree that second-order logic is required to characterize pro-verb constructions.

Comment: You seem to be saying pronouns share "reference" and pro-verbs share "meaning".  What's the difference between "reference" and "meaning"?

Comment: My mistake, then. Thanks. And I didn't say it was necessary to characterize pro-verb constructions; those are rarely that complex. I simply meant that the consistency requirements of mathematical practice have no relation to actual language performance and comprehension. Nor to individuals' actual beliefs about language performance and comprehension.

Comment: @MichaelHardy, If I could tell you what meaning is, I would be rich and famous.  But a reasonable approximation for that, in this context, is logical form.  So, as an approximation, let's say that same meaning implies same logical form.  E.g., "John likes shrimp, and Mary does, too" has the same meaning, and the same logical form, as "John likes shrimp, and Mary likes shrimp, too."  The identity required for the pro-verb construction is the identity between the lf of "likes shrimp" in the first clause and "likes shrimp" in the second clause, whatever exactly that is, in lf. (cont.)

Comment: ... (cont.)   It has nothing to do with reference to things in the world -- it concerns the relation between linguistic expressions (identity between verb phrases, in this case).

Comment: @GregLee: Sorry, I didn't mean to put it that way. What I meant was, why do you state that co-reference is defining for the function of pronouns? Or do I completely misunderstand you? ;-)

Comment: @IvanKapitonov, definite pronouns, I said, require coreference (or, better, coindexing).  I am just repeating George Lakoff's analysis.  One argument he gave was that definite pronouns allow cross-nested antecedents and antecedent-contained pronouns (e.g., Karttunen's "the MIG that shot at the pilot who chased it").  Pro-verbs, however, do not allow such constructions.

Comment: @GregLee, "Pro-verbs, however, do not allow such constructions", interesting! I find a sentence like "I liked it, but talked to a man who said he didn't" grammatical, isn't "did" in "didn't" doing pro-verb work for "liked it" here? Or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: @dainichi, In your example, there is no problem finding the antecedent for the 0 after "he didn't" -- it is simply "like it".  But try constructing an example of a pro-verb that is within its own antecedent.  Take as a model "[[i] the MIG that shot at the pilot who chased it[i]]", where the antecedent of "it" is the entire noun phrase which contains the "it" (as I've tried to indicate with brackets).  Which MIG was chased by that pilot?  It was the MIG that shot at the pilot who chased that very MIG.